# Identify 'flat' areas in a histogram?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the 'flat' areas in a histogram - really just a 1d array. When I say 'flat' I mean where the line is close to zero (<25) for long periods. An example of the histogram I am working with is:

```
0, 5, 9, 2, 8, 112, 12, 1, 20, 331  # my_array
```

So I want to identify the indexes as groups. So in the above example I would have 2 groups/tuples: `(0,1,2,3,4), (6,7,8)`. Can you suggest how I could do this in numpy efficiently?

My first step is to simply use `np.where(my_array < 25)`. This gives me an array like this `(True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False)`. How can I then rearrange that into groups/tuples/np.arrays in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

[`argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) is your friend to get the indices where the condition is met. We then group them with [`consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

```
import more_itertools as mit

condition = my_array < 25
[tuple(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(np.argwhere(condition).flatten())]
```

Result:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 8)]
```